# How can I draw a family tree for blended / adoptive families?

Tags: family-tree

I would like to draw a family tree, but I don't know how to represent some of the relations in the family.

How can I show:

1. both the adoptive parents and the birth parents for an adopted child
2. step daughters and sons

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  I'd like to encourage you to take the [tour] and look at our guidelines in the [help] about what kinds of questions are [on-topic](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Your question has more than one question in it -- and asking for book recommendations is the kind of subjective question where each answer might be equally valid -- see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  I've edited your question and its title to bring it in line with the site's guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way to distinguish between adoptive and birth parents in a family tree.  I would just show two sets of parents instead of the usual one, possibly adding an annotation.  Some websites and programs let you distinguish among different types of parents.

Showing step-children seems straightforward.  Just show them as being descended from their biological parents.  The marriage relationship should make clear who their step families are:

```
Jane = Mike = Carole = John
     |               |
    Greg           Marcia
```

Greg and Marcia are step-siblings because their parents are married to each other.

Comment: Just a small tweak - I like to include the marriage order number with the marriage symbol. Otherwise, it can get pretty confusing.

Comment: @bgwiehle Agreed.